# Transmitting JSON Django

Tags: python, django

I have a request for a model

```
paymentparking = paidparking.objects.filter(expirationdate__range=(startdate, enddate))
```

I need to take 2 fields from the request and pass them to JS
I send it via

```
return JsonResponse({'price': paymentparking.price,'expirationdate':paymentparking.expirationdate})
```

But I get an error АttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'price'

Comment: Share your `paidparking` model.

Comment: You are returning a queryset. You can get 'price' in a loop or convert to dictionary like the answer suggest

Comment: I need to send this to JS and take all the data from the records in the fields there price,expirationdate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to access an attribute of your Model (paidparking) but you are actually using the result of the queryset. If you want to have the list of expirationdate and price, use `values`.

```
paymentparking = paidparking.objects.filter(expirationdate__range=(startdate, enddate)).values('expirationdate', 'price')
return JsonResponse(dict(paymentparking))
```

Comment: And how do I get it now in JS? `$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "statistics",
    data: {
      'startdate': finalDateStrStart,'enddate': finalDateStrEnd,
    },
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
        success:function (data) {
            
        }
    });`

Comment: Read the data with `data.json()`. After that you can iterate over the data to do whatever you want.

Comment: Can I give you an example? I don't quite understand how to do thi